# LOCK FILE PHP for read then cannot be read?

Tags: php, file, locking

I am locking files but then when I read them I cannot, my code...

```
// ACQUIRE READ LOCK
if(flock($file, LOCK_SH)) {
// READ HASHES FILE
if($contents = file('haasdas.txt')) {
    // RELEASE READ LOCK
    flock($file, LOCK_UN);
} else {
            echo 'errrrrrorzzzer';
      }
}
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) mention, `flock()` works not on a filename, but on a file descriptor:

```
$fd=fopen($filename,'rb');
while (!flock($fd,LOCK_SH)) usleep(500);
$fs=fstat($fd);
$contents=fread($fd,$fs['size']);
flock($fd,LOCK_UN);
fclose($fd);
```

error handling is left as an exercise to the reader ...